# ASP MVC Binding Failed to Entity Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I'm in a situation where I'm uploading an image in my view, which should then populate the UploadedFile property in my Components entity in the model. However, the property is never reached for some reason. If I put in a Name though, there's no problem. Am I missing some detail here?

```
public partial class Components
{   
    public string Name { get; set; } // This gets set
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; } // This doesn't gets set
    public byte[] Image { get { return ConvertToByte(UploadedFile); } set { ; } }

    public byte[] ConvertToByte(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        uploadedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        return imageBytes;
    }
}
```

View with file upload:

```
@model EmbeddedStock.Models.ComponentViewModel

     div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentModel.Image, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
                Choose File...
                <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" Size="40" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; left: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; background-color: transparent; color: transparent"
                       onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'/>
            </a>
            <span class="label label-info" id="upload-file-info"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The ComponentViewModel:

```
public class ComponentViewModel
{
    public Components ComponentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, even if I try and change the name to "Name" or something else, to see if it was that specific property, nothing happens.

Comment: Oops, that should have been `name="ComponentModel.UploadedFile"`

Comment: That did the trick! Can't believe I didn't think of that..

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Stephen Muecke, changing the 'name' in the input field in the view did the job.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentModel.Image, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
            Choose File...
            <input type="file" name="ComponentModel.UploadedFile" Size="40" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; left: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; background-color: transparent; color: transparent"
                   onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'/>
        </a>
        <span class="label label-info" id="upload-file-info"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As another suggestion, use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComponentModel.UploadedFile, new { type = "file", size = "40" .... })` - always use the strongly typed helpers to generate your html when binding to model properties